# Collision side detection

Tags: game-physics, collision

I'm creating something like game engine using typescript. The game itself is rendered in canvas. Currently I'm working on bodies' collisions. I have a question and maybe someone can help me with resolving it.

I have two rectangles. One of them is like a player controlled with keyboard. Another one is a wall, with which player can be collided and must stop moving through the wall. Both, player and wall, have `x1, x2, y1, y2` coordinates, which are used for collision detection.

So maybe someone can explain me, please, how to compute which side was collided - left, top, right or bottom?

If you might be interested in this project, u r welcome to my repository

https://github.com/NickSettler/game003

Answer (score 0):

Try to add border regions like on the picture :

[image: sub rectangles]